# How to reverse numbers in string and keep same order for letters

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting

How can I reverse just the numbers in string of mixed character types (letters, numbers, spaces) but keep the rest of the string in same order?

**Example input:**

```
Dlasdf234dkl sdfkl8886adaf15adfjk7  asdflkj376661a s445s198
```

**Example output:**

```
Dlasdf432dkl sdfkl6888adaf51adfjk7  asdflkj166673a s544s891
```

I tried with some `preg_*` functions and regular expressions, but I couldn't manage to get the result demonstrated in my output example.

Comment: Please show what you've tried to far and people may be able to provide feedback on your code.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to see your regex attempt(s), but I think regex is a good plan. I would maybe think about doing a callback instead of just matching, something like this:

```
# match digits in the regex
echo preg_replace_callback('/[\d]+/',function($v){
    # reverse string
    return strrev($v[0]);
},$str);
```

Comment: Finnaly i did like this                                                                        <?php

$string="Dlasdf234dkl sdfkl8886adaf15adfjk7  asdflkj376661a s445s198";



$patterns = [];

$numbers = preg_match_all('!\d+!', $string, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
  foreach ($match as $m) {
   $patterns[$m] = strrev($m);
  }
 }

 $output = strtr($string, $patterns);

 echo $output;

?>

Comment: Actually a mix of yours and mine is probably the best solution, certainly the least amount of lines. I never thought of `strrev()` so that was a good idea. If you do `preg_replace_callback()` you can remove all the looping and do each replacement as it finds it in the string.

Comment: TY one more time, personally i think your solution is better because your code is shorter then mine. I can say that learn something new and useful, but this (your code solution) is still not my level of knowledge.